# How to install node.js with GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio, software-installation, node.js

I am trying to install `node.js` on my Raspberry Pi as well as `GPIO`.

I am running a brand new install of Debian Jessie

I could get nodejs v.0.10.29 installed. No matter what I do, this is pretty much the most recent package I have been able to install even if a lot of post I read are speaking of version 4.0.0.

However v0.10.29 is running and I could run a simple http server.

The problem comes when I try to install GPIO. I have tried the following;

- rpi-gpio
- pi-gpio
- onoff

I can't get any of them to work and I have played around trying anything I could find on the web to fix it. I have tried pretty much everything.

So, since I probably messed up a lot of things, I reinstalled the OS Debian *{Ed: Raspbian}* Jessie and will give it another shot.

From there, what should I do after my OS is installed to get this to work?

Anyone have a good set of instruction for this - because I am probably missing something, right?

If anyone is willing to help I would gladly follow instructions and post any error messages I'm getting, because so far this is all I have been getting.

So I guess I will start with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

What's next?

**EDIT #1 Nodejs v0.10.29 is installed**

I have installed Nodejs as suggested by Joan:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.3.1/node-v4.3.1-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
tar xf node-v4.3.1-linux-armv6l.tar.xz  
cd node-v4.3.1-linux-armv6l/ 
sudo cp -R * /usr/local

nodejs -v
```

returned;

v0.10.29

**EDIT#2 pi-gpio install**

Now that node is installed I have try to turn a led on on pin 18 and got the following error;

```
module.js:340 
throw err; 
^ 
Error: Cannot find module 'pi-gpio' 
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) 
at Module.require (module.js:364:17) 
at require (module.js:380:17) 
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/NODE/http.js:22:12) 
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) 
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

So I have installed pi-gpio using npm;

```
sudo npm install pi-gpio
```

I am now getting this error;

```
Error when trying to open pin 18
/bin/sh: 1: gpio-admin: not found

Error when trying to close pin 18
/bin/sh: 1: gpio-admin: not found
```

So I will now install gpio-admin.

And this where it get messy because gpio-admin is old and wont install on the Debian Jessie So if anyone can come up with a way to turn on a led from Nodejs under Debian Jessie that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how to get `*GPIO*` working with `*Nodejs*`.

Let me tell you that this was far from being Plug and play.

```
**OS** : *Raspbian Jessie*
```

`**Nodejs**: *Version 4.3.1*` ( Credit to joan)

Note that you should remove any old installation of `*Nodejs*`.

I have updated `*npm*` with the following command;

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

Then I have installed `*gpio v0.2.7*`;

```
 sudo npm install gpio
```

and got the folowing warning;

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
```

So I will have to deal with that.

Then I have installed `*rpi-gpio*`;

```
sudo npm install rpi-gpio
```

Still got the warning about `package.json`. At this point my script was working I could reach the server and my led light came on.

Other install I have made due to warning and errors:

```
sudo npm install graceful-fs@^4.0.0
sudo npm install node-gyp
```

I'm not sure that the last 2 installs where needed but it ended up working so you might want to try that to.

Answer (score 7):

For example to install RPi nodejs version 4.3.1 (see below for other versions)

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.3.1/node-v4.3.1-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
tar xf node-v4.3.1-linux-armv6l.tar.xz  
cd node-v4.3.1-linux-armv6l/ 
sudo cp -R * /usr/local
```

Check installation with

```
node -v
```

---

Different versions are available from https://nodejs.org/dist/

For the Pi2B make sure you download a linux-arm7l build, for all other Pis make sure you download a linux-arm6l build.

Comment: Thank you will try that version. So far that distributor always returned me 404.

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting a 404 response

Comment: I followed those instructions just before I posted and have just repeated the wget without problem.  Can you ping nodejs.org?

Comment: yes I can. Do I have to sudo wget?

Comment: No, sudo is not required (it wouldn't give a 404 error).  Make sure you cut&paste the wget line.  You may prefer a later version.  Look in https://nodejs.org/dist and make sure you download an arm6l version.  I'm not sure if 6l will also work on a Pi2B.

Comment: Got it. But is it normal that nodejs -v  return v0.10.29?

Comment: I have no idea.  I don't use node.js.  To see the node version try node -v.  Hopefully that will be whatever you ended up downloading.

Comment: To clarify on my Pi, after downloading version 5.6 I get npm -v 3.6.0, nodejs -v V4.2.6, node -v v5.6.0.  I have no idea what those numbers actually mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36087/discussion-between-madeindreams-and-joan).

Comment: @MadeInDreams make sure that you're typing in the *.tar.xz name correctly (note that the last char before the extension is a lowercase "L" not a "1", could be easily mistaken).  I have just run through these steps and successfully updated node to v4.3.1.  `node -v` should return `v4.3.1`, not the older version that you're returning.