# Installing NodeSource Node.js v7 on Raspberry Pi 1

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, node.js, pi-1

I want to install NodeSource Node.js v7 on my Raspberry Pi 1, but when I run the code: 
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -`,
I am presented with:

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js v7.x repo...

## You appear to be running on ARMv6 hardware. Unfortunately this is not currently 
supported by the NodeSource Linux distributions. Please use the 'linux-armv6l' binary 
tarballs available directly from nodejs.org for Node.js v4 and later.
```

How can I install Node.js v7 on a Raspberry Pi 1?

Comment: That message is telling me you can't.

Comment: So there in no way that I can do that then @joan ?

Comment: [How to Install or Upgrade to Node.js v7 on the Raspberry Pi](http://thisdavej.com/how-to-install-or-upgrade-to-node-js-v7-on-the-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: @DRM as fas as I am aware you need a Pi2 or Pi3, i.e. a four core Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow a similar procedure as [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/77483/17798). I.e.

1. Uninstall original
2. Re-install newer one but compiled for ArmV6.