# npm packages not working when I install them

Tags: pi-3

I am currently working on a coding project, and would like to test them on my RaspPi. All of the code works when I run it on travis-ci. However, when I run it on RaspPi nothing happens. Here is a simplified version:

```
~$ npm install jsdoc
# bunch of stats that all report success
~$ jsdoc --help
~$ jsdoc --help
```

As you can see, jsdoc is outputting nothing, as if it never installed. But the following shows it is installed:

```
~$ jsdoc
bash: jsdoc: command not found
~$ npm install jsdoc
~$ jsdoc --help
~$ jsdoc --help
```

For the full repo, look here: https://github.com/FreezePhoenix/XtraUtils/tree/JavaScript

Comment: The methods suggested by @Aurora0001 do not work.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it's a Node verson issue. How did you install Node on your Pi? Could you also check the version with `node -v`?

Comment: @Aurora0001 different device and comments work.

Comment: I installed node using `sudo apt-get install node` which installed it as `nodejs`... and `node -v` gives nothing.

Comment: Hmm, is this Raspbian Jessie on the problematic Pi? If so, that would probably explain it.

Comment: Yep. Jessie is the installed one, installed with noobs.

Comment: NOOBS isn't your OS, it's a tool that you would have used to install an OS (most likely Raspbian). You can get your OS version with `cat /etc/os-release`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78073/discussion-between-freezephoenix-and-aurora0001).

Comment: why are you using differrent commands in your second example?  it does not prove that there is a problem with the first example   .......... using `jsdoc` command in the second example does not prove that `jsdoc --help` failed ..... a fail will be proven only if you use `jsdoc --help` in the second example and you get a help doc

Comment: @jsotola Will fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original thought that it was a global/local installation issue was incorrect. The issue is probably caused by using the `nodejs` package from the repositories instead of directly from Node. On Jessie, `nodejs` [v0.10.29](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/nodejs) is provided, and on Stretch, [v4.8.2](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/nodejs). Version 0.10 is from 2013, which is, in Node terms, ancient.

JSDoc isn't compatible with 0.10.29 (the Jessie version), but it is compatible with 4.8.2:

> JSDoc supports Node.js 4.2.0 and later. You can install JSDoc globally or in your project's node_modules folder.

You can either:

- [Upgrade to Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/)
- [install a more recent version of Node](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/45319/58316) without upgrading to Stretch.

Comment: Your suggestions did not work, neither the first one nor the second one.

Comment: Thanks. I can now use npm... It wasn't just jsdoc, it was every npm package. Thanks!

Comment: @FreezePhoenix So, what fixed it?

Comment: @Mast https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44840243#44840243